# Why the method added to object lost?

Tags: javascript, types, casting

String has a bold method, I want to add a similar h1 method to it. The adding seems right, but when I call it, an error says h1 is not a function. What's wrong with the code? Any help will be highly appreciated!

[image: the run and error screen shoot]

Answer (score 1):

### A short answer

```
s = new String("Hello World")
s.h1 = () => "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

Then you can call s.h1() normally

### A long answer

This is due to the implicitly type casting.

```
s = "Hello World"
typeof s  // is "string"
s = new String("Hello World")
typeof s  // is "object"
```

The `bold()` is a method of String object, `"Hello World"` is a primitive type, it does not have any methods. But why you can call `"Hello World".bold()`? Because when you read property or call method of a primitive type, JavaScript do the implicitly type casting for you. It encapsulate a **new** corresponding object **every time**.

- When you adding `h1` method to the primitive type `"Hello World"`, it updates the previous encapsulating object.
- When you calling `h1` method, it asks the second encapsulating object which does not have the `h1` method.

This is a kind of obscure JavaScript type casting fault, hard to detect and diagnose.